# Getting error when trying to dispay multiple selecterize inputs on the same plot in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to plot a scatter plot with multiple inputs using the selectize input with multiple = TRUE.

Basically, I have a list of different genes, and I want to plot them against each other using a scatter plot. 
I can select 2 genes and plot them against each other fine, but what I want to be able to do is select one gene to plot on the Y axis, and then select several others to plot against it on the X axis at the same time and on the same plot via `selectizeInput( multiple = TRUE)` . currently the below code works fine for a single pair of genes, but as soon as I select another gene to plot against the gene on the Y axis I get `Error: more than one expression parsed`

I know that there should be some way of doing this via the dpylr package, but when I have tried doing that I couldn't figure out how to only select a few selected columns, rather than melting the entire table.

My shiny code, limited to the relevant section, and shortened version of my data table are below.

```
> Short_cortex5
                         Names MARC1 MARC2 MARCH1  SEPT1    DEC1 MARCH2  SEPT2
    1 GTEX-1117F-3226-SM-5N9CT 4.459 15.30  2.501 1.0680 0.02610  81.15  66.14
    2 GTEX-111FC-3126-SM-5GZZ2 6.902 16.07  4.700 0.2980 0.00000  68.90  88.95
    3 GTEX-1128S-2726-SM-5H12C 5.361 17.27  2.462 0.3812 0.00000  63.41  65.20
    4 GTEX-117XS-3026-SM-5N9CA 4.792 11.37  3.107 0.5550 0.02261  84.53  48.98
    5 GTEX-1192X-3126-SM-5N9BY 5.772 21.76  6.123 0.7558 0.00000  88.49 106.20
    6 GTEX-11DXW-1126-SM-5H12Q 5.143 15.55  4.239 0.5859 0.03581  58.91  69.80
    7 GTEX-11DXY-3226-SM-5GIDE 3.856 16.74  4.596 0.6551 0.02627  70.38  68.50
    8 GTEX-11EI6-3026-SM-5GZZO 6.386 11.48  2.167 0.3567 0.01090  60.14  74.04


library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
#TPM5
GeneNames <- colnames(Short_cortex5[2:ncol(Short_cortex5)])
# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Cell specific gene expression enrichment"),

  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "gene_X",
                     label = "Select gene X:",
                     choices = GeneNames,
                     selected = "MARCH1",
                     multiple = TRUE),

      selectizeInput(inputId = "gene_Y",
                     label = "Select gene Y:",
                     choices = GeneNames,
                     selected = "SEPT1")
    ),
        # Show a plot 
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "corrPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$corrPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$gene_X)
    ggplot(data = Short_cortex5, aes_string(x=input$gene_X, y=input$gene_Y)) +
      geom_point()  +
      geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
      scale_x_log10() + 
      scale_y_log10()
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know I could just manually create ggplot rows for each possibility, which is feasable if I was just wanting to display a short, fixed number of of inputs, but not when I want to be able to select multiple at once.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = Short_cortex5, aes(x = Short_cortex5$SEPT2, y = Short_cortex5$MARC1)) +
  geom_smooth(data = Short_cortex5, aes(x = Short_cortex5$SEPT2, y = Short_cortex5$MARC1), method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  geom_point(data = Short_cortex5, aes(x = Short_cortex5$SEPT2, y = Short_cortex5$MARC2)) +
  geom_smooth(data = Short_cortex5, aes(x = Short_cortex5$SEPT2, y = Short_cortex5$MARC2), method = lm, se = FALSE)
```